# No woobly windows in ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, compiz

i've updated and installed compizconfig settings-manager by running below command,

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra
```

But my wobbly window is still disabled?

Please help !

Answer (score 3):

Installing compiz and it's plugins doesnot enable the woobly windows effect by default.You have to manually enable it.For this,

Open compizconfig settings manager and then move to Effects and enable the woobly windows option.

[image]